# get current user location using google maps api with react native?

Tags: react-native, google-maps-api-3, react-redux

i'm currently working on a project using google maps api with react native, but i'm struggling to handle get current user location with redux, this is my action ,how can i fix it :
import MAPSActionTypes from "./mapsactiontypes";

```
export const currentlocation = () => {
  return   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
       (position) => {
         console.log("wokeeey");
         console.log(position);
         {payload: position}
       },
       (error) => console.log(error)),
       { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're error is exactly, but I found an issue [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/1183) on doing the exact same thing. It referred to a code sample you can find [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/209#issuecomment-350907665), which I've reproduced below.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'

const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.01;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.01;

const initialRegion = {
  latitude: -37.78825,
  longitude: -122.4324,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
}

class MyMapView extends React.Component {

  map = null;

  state = {
    region: {
      latitude: -37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    },
    ready: true,
    filteredMarkers: []
  };

  setRegion(region) {
    if(this.state.ready) {
      setTimeout(() => this.map.mapview.animateToRegion(region), 10);
    }
    //this.setState({ region });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Component did mount');
    this.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  getCurrentPosition() {
    try {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          const region = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
          };
          this.setRegion(region);
        },
        (error) => {
          //TODO: better design
          switch (error.code) {
            case 1:
              if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
                Alert.alert("", "Para ubicar tu locación habilita permiso para la aplicación en Ajustes - Privacidad - Localización");
              } else {
                Alert.alert("", "Para ubicar tu locación habilita permiso para la aplicación en Ajustes - Apps - ExampleApp - Localización");
              }
              break;
            default:
              Alert.alert("", "Error al detectar tu locación");
          }
        }
      );
    } catch(e) {
      alert(e.message || "");
    }
  };

  onMapReady = (e) => {
    if(!this.state.ready) {
      this.setState({ready: true});
    }
  };

  onRegionChange = (region) => {
    console.log('onRegionChange', region);
  };

  onRegionChangeComplete = (region) => {
    console.log('onRegionChangeComplete', region);
  };

  render() {

    const { region } = this.state;
    const { children, renderMarker, markers } = this.props;

    return (
      <MapView
        showsUserLocation
        ref={ map => { this.map = map }}
        data={markers}
        initialRegion={initialRegion}
        renderMarker={renderMarker}
        onMapReady={this.onMapReady}
        showsMyLocationButton={false}
        onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
        onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        textStyle={{ color: '#bc8b00' }}
        containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', borderColor: '#BC8B00'}}>

        {markers.map(renderMarker)}

        {children && children || null}

      </ClusteredMapView>
    );
  }
}

export default MyMapView;
```

Comment: thank u man , u'r using state, in my case i want to handle the state by redux (redux-saga)

Comment: Does this work, though? It's important to distinguish between whether the problem is being caused by `redux` or `react-native-maps`.